# http flu season question python not sure why im getting this output

Tags: python, http

Write a function named "flu_season" that doesn't take any parameters. Study the documentation for this API that tracks tweets containing flu symptoms (http://www.flutrack.org). Send a request to the url "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/" which will use the same format as the linked API (ex. instead of connecting to http://api.flutrack.org/ use https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/, but use the same query string as you would with the linked API). Return the total number of tweets containing flu symptoms over the past 2 days

Note: We are using a local API to avoid limits on the free API and for grading consistent grading. Feel free to explore the linked API while testing

```
import urllib.request
   def flu_season():
   url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/?a=True&time=2"
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   url1 = response.read().decode()
   return url1
```

error on input []: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sandbox/python/run_function.py", line 115, in 
call_all(submission_file_path, function_name, all_inputs_filename, results_filename, written_filename, sql_output_filename)
File "sandbox/python/run_function.py", line 102, in call_all
print(all_results)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 103-109: ordinal not in range(128)

how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you look at what your url looks after glueing it? You are missing  & in between the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/?" + "a = True" + "time = 2"
```

This will cause `url` to have the value `https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/?a = Truetime = 2`. The part after the question mark does not look like a valid query string to me. Query strings typically do not have spaces, and the key-value pairs are typically separated with ampersands.

Perhaps instead you could do:

```
url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/flutrack/?a=True&time=2"
```

Comment: ah okay, so i did that and a new traceback error came up, as shown in my edited question, not sure if im missing a line of code or not

Comment: figured it out thanks i wasn't returning the total number initially